# I want to check my proof valificated

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, complete-spaces

I am trying to solve problems. Two problem is as follows.

> Q1 suppose $f_k$ defined on $\Bbb R^n$ converge uniformly to a
>   function $f$. suppose that each $f_k$ is bounded, say by $A_k$, prove
>   that $f$ is bounded.

here is my proof

given $\varepsilon =1 $ , $\exists N \in \Bbb N$ such that 
$$||f_k(x)-f(x)||\lt 1 $$ 
for all $x \in \Bbb R^n$ and $k \ge N$

since $f_k$ is bounded by $A_k$, by triangle inequality
$$||f(x)||\le ||f_k(x)-f(x)||+||f_k(x)|| \le 1+A_k$$

if $1\le k \le N-1$, Let $M_0=max\{A_1+1,A_2+2,\cdots, A_{N-1}+1 \}$

Then, for all $k=1,2,\cdots N, N+1, \cdots $
$$||f(x)|| \le M = max\{M_0,A_k+1\}$$

Thus $f$ is bounded

> Q2 Let V be a complete normed vector space.
>
> (a) Let $(f_n)$be a cauchy sequence in $C([a,b],V)$. show that for each $x\in[a,b]$, $(f_n(x))$is cauchy, and so define the pointwise  limit $f(x) =\lim_{n\to >\infty}{f_n(x)}$
>
> (b) prove that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly.
>
> (c) prove that f is continuous, and deduce that $C([a,b],V)$ is complete.

I was stucked by problem above Q2, because no norm isn't given in $C([a,b],V)$.
I wander if it is fault of book. or can I Prove above problem for arbitrary norm in $C([a,b],V)$? if the norm is sup norm in $C([a,b],V)$, I might be able to solve this problem. please advise me ! I need your help. thank you

Comment: For Q1, I think after you derive $||f(x)||\le ||f_k(x)-f(x)||+||f_k(x)|| \le 1+A_k$, it hold for every k, so  $||f(x)||\le ||f_k(x)-f(x)||+||f_k(x)|| \le \inf 1+A_k$, then it's bounded

Comment: and you should define $M$ as the sum of the above inf, the max of $||f_k(x)-f(x)||$, and the max of $A_k$ for $k \leq n$